# load an XML file into kafka topic without schema

Tags: xml, apache-kafka

I'm trying to load a rather large XML file into a kafka topic. I know how to load JSON, AVRO etc. but those are parsed out well in topics because their schemas can be inferred. How do I do this with XML? how can I set a key for the XML messages?

I tried something like this

`confluent kafka topic produce test1 --parse-key --delimiter , < NameOfFile.xml`

but this just produced each line of the XML file as a new message (just text in value).

The XML file looks something like the following (but much longer):

```
<Mp ver="3" id="517131">
      <Fields>
        <aexst>N</aexst>
        <chexst>N</chexst>
        <clueexst />
        <ocdexst>N</ocdexst>
        <id>123</id>
```

I want the message key to say:

`123`

and the message value to be (just a string of the XML file):

```
<Mp ver="3" id="517131">
      <Fields>
        <aexst>N</aexst>
        <chexst>N</chexst>
        <clueexst />
        <ocdexst>N</ocdexst>
        <id>123</id>
```

How do I go about doing this without a connector?

Comment: could you share an example of how the XML looks like and what would you like to produce to kafka?

Comment: @GerardGarcia added that information in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use [`kcat`](https://github.com/edenhill/kcat), or some other tool, to produce to Kafka instead of using the confluent one.

If you just want to publish one file

```
kcat -P -b <broker_url> -t <topic> -p <partition_number> -k <key - 123 in your example> file.xml
```

You'll need to be careful to choose the appropriate partition for your message or just set `-1` to send it to a random partition.

If you don't want to hard-code the key in the command or you have multiple files, you can use [`yq`](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq) to extract the key from the file programmatically and feed it to the `kcat` command.